# How to reprogram ADY501?

Tags: programming, remote-control

I have wireless controlled room light with remote, it has two buttons: ON and OFF. Everything was working fine until recently.

I was sitting on my bed with a laptop and decided to go to the kitchen get myself something to drink, so I put laptop on bed, get up and while leaving my room light turned off. I must placed my laptop onto remote and it turned off lights, it's fine, since it happened few times already. When I returned I noticed that remote works differently, instead of pressing ON to turning on lights and OFF to turn them off now it's ON to turn them on and again ON to turn them off, OFF button is not doing anything except turning on led on remote. I opened remote and there is a so8 chip "ADY501 1912", ADY501 is mentioned in this package on the Internet, but I can't find datasheet, and 1912 looks like date of production (12th week of 2019). On PCB there are 4 pads for buttons, I tried to short them and remote's led is turning on.

At this point my best guess what happened is: this chip can support up to 4 buttons and number of buttons can be somehow set by pressing buttons. When I placed my laptop on remote I accidentally switch number of buttons from 2 to 1.

Any one know how to set it back to two buttons?

Comment: `number of buttons can be somehow set by pressing buttons` ... probably not ... that would cause too many problems like yours .... but a slim possibility does exist